# JavaScript onload or init or ...?

Tags: javascript

What is the best practice for loading an external .js file into an .html file? (no inline calls e.g., `<body onload="...`)

I have a basic HTML page where I'd like to load an external .js file. When I have the code in a script tag at the bottom of my HTML page everything works as it should.

However if I cut the js code and paste it into an external .js file and call the file from either the bottom of the `<head>` tag or place the call to the script just above the closing `</body>` tag the script doesn't run.

Unsuccessful, but I've also tried wrapping the code in the external .js file in:

```
function init() {
    // Put your code here
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: How about posting the `<script>` tag that didn't work for you when you tried to load the external .js file.

Comment: Any errors in the console? (e.g. in Chrome View->Developer->JavaScript Console)? You could also look in the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools (View->Developer->Developer tools) for files not found, and similar problems.

Comment: If you want an answer, you really need to provide more information. As it stands, your question will likely be closed.

Comment: I used `<script type="text/javascript" src="...correct.path.to...file.js"></script>` in both `<head>` and before the closing `</body>` tag and the script still isn't running. Page Inspector in Visual Studio shows "0" problems with the page. Chrome says _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="url.blah/folder/file.js"></script>
```

This will make the Javascript code accessible from other external javascript files, as well as inline Javascript.

Comment: I thought you were right because I found I was calling the file without declaring the `type="text/javascript"` however when I use `<script type="text/javascript" src="...file.js"></script>` the script still doesn't run. This is bizarre.

Comment: Gotta love JavaScript. I had a single "?" character in the middle of my code accidentally typed into my script. This is corrected and working as it should. @thatidiotguy is correct in how to call .js files.